# AWS Cognito - attributes validations regex

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using Cognito as a identity provider in my app and I can't find the valid regex for email and phone.

Please assist me.

Comment: Can you post the regex that you're using? also the error?

Comment: I don't know what is the regex, this is my question

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/16442705) for email addresses and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109237/16442705) for phone numbers will help.

Comment: This is not the right regex for Cognito phone validation